# @s3_direct_post.fields: No implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am completly new to Ruby and Rails and have gotten stuck following this tutorial. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails

The error I am getting is when I navigate to http://localhost:3000/users/new and is as follows.

> TypeError in Users#new
>
> Showing /home/tomt/myapp/app/views/users/_form.html.erb where line #1
>   raised:
>
> no implicit conversion of nil into String Extracted source (around
>   line #1): <%= form_for(@user, html: { class: 'directUpload', data: {
>   'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), 'url' => @s3_direct_post.url,
>   'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } }) do |f| %>

I believe the problem is being caused by @s3_direct_post.fields because if I replace it with 'form-data' => (Hash.new) then the page loads. However, this is not a valid fix. Why is @s3_direct_post.fields nill? and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure this out, in my aws.rb I was using AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID however in my actual Environment I had defined it as AWS_ACCESS_KEY which is missing the _ID.

The error Rails gave me --pasted below-- sent me on a total wild goose chase. I only found the true cause after retracing my steps through the tutorial many, many times.

> no implicit conversion of nil into String Extracted source (around
>   line #1): <%= form_for(@user, html: { class: 'directUpload', data: {
>   'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), 'url' => @s3_direct_post.url,
>   'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } }) do |f| %>

O well, it was a good lesson and maybe my experience will help someone in the future.

Comment: I had the same error: Essentially if your environment variables are not exactly correct you will get this error. Check these: ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']